# Issues with webbrowser in online Python IDE

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I am trying to use an online IDE called repl.it and use the webbrowser module to open a webpage. This is the code I use:

```
from webbrowser import *
webbrowser.open('https://reddit.com')
```

But the function returns `False` as indicated in the online console.

Does this possibly have to do with the fact that the program runs in a remote server? If so, does `repl.it` have a hook between the server and the client to be able to perform web browser manipulations?

Comment: _"I think this may have something to do with the fact I am using an online IDE"_ - Yes, that's correct. Think about. You're running Python in an _online environment_, on a _remote_ server. Would the code you're running affect your _local_ machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yev from Repl.it here, that would be returning false because webbrowser probably needs a browser to execute and, additionally, repl.it runs code on headless machines, meaning there is no gui to run browsers in